# Expect -re not failing on eof

Tags: tcl, expect

I have the following expect script.

This is `test.exp`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

# exp_internal 1
# log_file -noappend ~/expect.log

# Use `send_log` to print to log file

set timeout 30

set bold [exec tput bold]
set red [exec tput setaf 1]
set green [exec tput setaf 2]
set normal [exec tput sgr0]

proc test_label {value} {
  upvar bold bold
  upvar normal normal
  puts "Running ${bold}${value}${normal}…"
}
proc test_send {value} {
  sleep 0.1
  send "$value"
}
proc test_failed {} {
  upvar bold bold
  upvar red red
  upvar normal normal
  sleep 0.1
  puts "${bold}${red}Failed${normal}"
  exit 1
}
proc test_ok {{force_close false}} {
  upvar bold bold
  upvar green green
  upvar normal normal
  sleep 0.1
  puts "${bold}${green}OK${normal}"
  if {$force_close} {
    close
  }
}

expect_before {
  default {
    test_failed
  }
}
```

This is `electrum.exp`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

source ./test.exp

test_label "Should create Electrum mnemonic"

spawn qr-backup.sh --create-electrum-mnemonic

expect {
  -re {Format USB flash drive \(y or n\)\?} {
    test_send "n\r"
  }
}

expect {
  -re {\[sudo\] password for pi:} {
    test_send "$env(password)\r"
  }
}

expect {
  -re {Creating Electrum mnemonic…}
}

expect {
  -re {([a-z]+ ?){24}} {
    test_ok true
  }
}
```

Why doesn’t script fail when last line returned by `spawn qr-backup.sh --create-electrum-mnemonic` is `electrum: error: unrecognized arguments: --nbits 264`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out!

Solved using `eof` statement.

```
expect {
  -re {([a-z]+ ?){24}} {
    test_ok true
  }
  eof {
    test_failed
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to do the same thing in many places, consider using `expect_after { eof { test_failed }}`

Comment: The `default` pattern covers `eof`. Glenn jackman explains the real reason the code is not working. Replacing `expect_before {default {test_failed}}` with `expect_after {eof {test_failed}}` will not make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Note this from the expect man page:

> `expect_before [expect_args]`
>
> > Unless overridden by a `-i` flag, `expect_before` patterns match against the spawn id defined **at the time that the `expect_before` command was executed** (not when its pattern is matched).

(emphasis mine)

No spawn id was active when the `expect_before` command was executed.